# Correct way to inject bearer token in httpclient using IOC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, bearer-token

In our .NET 4.72 web application, I am trying to figure out, if we are adding Bearer tokens correctly.

- We are using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection v.2.1.1
- The access tokens are stored on the ClaimsPrincipal

This is how we currently configure the httpclient and one of the services using it:

```
public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<AccountService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ShopConfiguration.AccountBalanceServiceUrl);

            string token = GetTokenFromClaims();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
        });
}

private string GetTokenFromClaims()
{
    Claim token = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(claim => claim.Type == Authentication.Constants.Claims.ApiAccessToken);
    return token == null ? string.Empty : token.Value;
}
```

I want to ensure that every time a new user consumes the `AccountService`, it will be that user's accesstoken that is being used in the httpclient.

**Is this the correct way to add a Bearer token to the HttpClient?**

Comment: It seems to be right. Anyway if it works I don't see any problem

Comment: How is `GetTokenFromClaims` implemented.

Comment: @Nkosi I updated the original question with the GetTokenFromClaims implementation

Comment: I can't think of an issue here. Looks good for me